# x-editable - run code after successful POST?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, x-editable

I recently added x-editable functionality to my django project. I have it working to populate a combobox and submit my selection. It saves to the database, all working great. However I have a `div` i would like to update on successful submit/POST.

With the `source:` line below i can specify what happens after successful **GET** of the combobox values. (`success: function(data)....etc`)

I cannot figure out how to do the same after a successful **POST**.

**Javascript (with some django mixed in):**

```
$('#issueResponse').editable({
        disabled: true,
        type: 'select',
        url: '../ajax/post/issueresponse',
        params: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                },
        pk: {{ issue_obj.pk }},
        {% if issue_obj.fk_issueresponseTypeName.id == null %}
            //Do nothing
            //Do not include value: variable if existing value is set!
        {% else %}
            value: {{ issue_obj.fk_issueresponseTypeName.id }}, //value = the default value (id) of the combobox
        {% endif %}  
        showbuttons: true,

    source: function() {
        var result;
        $.ajax({
            url: '../ajax/get/responses',
            //data: {t: 'zone'},
            type: 'GET',
            global: false,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                result = data;
                //$( "#Response" ).load( "../ajax/get/{{issue_obj.id}}/response/" );
            }
        });
        return result;
    },
});
```

I have confirmed that `$( "#Response" ).load( "../ajax/get/{{issue_obj.id}}/response/"` works via a button (to refresh a specified 'div'). I have also added it into the `source:` -> `success:` area and it works as expected (in code snippet above but commented out). However of course I would like it to refresh **after** a successful POST by x-editable.

I have tried variations of the following:

- The below code added under `showbuttons: true,`

`success: function(data, config) { 
   $( "#Response" ).load( "../ajax/get/{{issue_obj.id}}/response/" 
   },`

- The below code expanded against `url:` as i thought it might follow similar approach to `source:`,`

  ```
  url: function() {
      var result;
      $.ajax({
          url: '../ajax/post/issueresponse',
          //data: {t: 'zone'},
          type: 'POST',
          global: false,
          async: false,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
              $( "#Response" ).load( "../ajax/get/{{issue_obj.id}}/response/" );
          }
      });
      return result;
  },
  ```

Neither have worked. Any suggestions?

===== The code below includes the solution by BabyAzerty ====

`Response` corresponds to `<div id="Response">` you would have your html

```
$('#issueResponse').editable({
        disabled: true,
        type: 'select',
        url: '../ajax/post/issueresponse',
        success: function(response, newValue) {
                          $( "#Response" ).load( "../ajax/get/{{issue_obj.id}}/response/" );
                          },
        params: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                },
        pk: {{ issue_obj.pk }},
        {% if issue_obj.fk_issueresponseTypeName.id == null %}
            //Do nothing
            //Do not include value: variable if existing value is set!
        {% else %}
            value: {{ issue_obj.fk_issueresponseTypeName.id }}, //value = the default value (id) of the combobox
        {% endif %}  
        showbuttons: true,

    source: function() {
        var result;
        $.ajax({
            url: '../ajax/get/responses',
            //data: {t: 'zone'},
            type: 'GET',
            global: false,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                result = data;
                //$( "#Response" ).load( "../ajax/get/{{issue_obj.id}}/response/" );
            }
        });
        return result;
    },
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the success param of X-Editable

```
$('#issueResponse').editable({
    success: function(response, newValue) {
        $( "#Response" ).load( "../ajax/get/{{issue_obj.id}}/response/" );
    }
});
```

Or you can add an event trigger

```
$('#issueResponse').on('save', function(e, params) {
    alert('Saved value: ' + params.newValue);
    $( "#Response" ).load( "../ajax/get/{{issue_obj.id}}/response/" );
});
```

Comment: Thanks BabyAzerty, I used the success param liked you suggested and it works great. I have updated my question to include the final working code.